# Schedule with Broadcast and Service in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, swiperefreshlayout

I want to perform the scheduling, how much time will it take to refresh the data once (this will call retrofit).

My class is organized as follows:

1. Activity.
2. Broadcast
3. Service

In Activity, I have the onRefresh () method to refresh data.
I want to make sure that the program will run onRefresh () once in a while.

```
public class App implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
 // something method

     public void getNewData(String city){
      // call API use update data
     }

     @Override
     public void onRefresh() {
     new Handler().postDelayed() -> { 
            getNewData(city) }; 
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        },1000);
     }
}
```

I search google, and found use BroadCast Can execute code even when the app is turned off.

I was able to schedule a delay time to re-run the code using onReceive () in Broadcast.

But I don't know how to implement onRefresh in Activity.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know After one certain time will update one time. you can use Manage system updates or Notification combined Service ... example Zalo. This is Recommend for u.

Comment: Thanks bro, but it's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Hoang, welcome to Stack Overflow. if you dont write code in your answer, please comment in question instead. Thank you